# Return object from hashset with lowest property?

Tags: c#, hashset

I want to get the object element from a hashset with minimal object.property value.

I can get it to return that value with:

```
int minProperty = collection.Min(c => c.property);
```

But i need the complete element or the index to get the element. Unfortunately unlike list a hashset does not have Find or IndexAt methods. Probably because it is not sorted like a list is.

```
Class MyItem
{
public int value;
public string text;
}

HashSet<MyItem> itemCollection = new HashSet<Myitem>() { new MyItem() { value = 4, text = "A"},
 new MyItem(){ value = 20, text = "B"}};

MyItem lowestFind = itemCollection.//??
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `OrderBy`, sort your items by `value` property in *ascending* order then get the First item:

```
itemCollection.OrderBy(x => x.value).First();
```

If you want to get the index too you can do the following:

```
var itemAndIndex = itemCollection
               .Select({x,idx} => new { item = x, index = idx})
               .OrderBy(a => a.item.value)
               .First();

var item = itemAndIndex.item;
var index = itemAndIndex.index;
```

Comment: So close... i had itemCollection.GroupBy(x => x.value), unsure what that does. Anyway what yours does: does it put the item i want at index [0]?

Comment: Thank you, i just did it manually and clocked it with StopWatch. My for loop is much faster then your first approach. 35ms for your approach, i can get my index in the for loop in 6ms. Probably because it is sorting the whole list with your approach, i just itterate and see if the value is lower -> then set the index number. This might deserves a new question though.

Comment: ofcourse the for loop will be faster.sorting is more expensive than iteration.

Comment: Yeah, so there is no build in method for just getting the lowest value?

Comment: I don't know is there a built-in method for `HashSet`.But if you use `List<T>` class instead, you can use [FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx) method which takes a predicate as parameter.

Comment: List is much slower for certain operations like comparing objects. I am actually figuring out how to store nodelists for A* in a more efficient way since my last algorithm was way to slow for what i'm planning. I will eventually go into hierarchical A* but an efficient container is the base.